# Browser disconnects when I refresh (or change the page) a page that also has the developer tools open. It happened after building a PWA (Error code)

Tags: browser, refresh, progressive-web-apps, developer-tools, lighthouse

When I have **any type** of page open and I go into the developer tools and hit refresh, the page just disconnects.  It started happening after I built a PWA and was using lighthouse. I am not sure how to fix this but I need it fixed. It happens only with chrome and brave

I get this error code:

> VM15:7288 crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: help]

just change this custom to low end tier mobile

Answer (score 0):

Had to set the mobile setting to "No throttling"